# Doing Indiana Jones-style traced maps online

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

This is becoming more and more of an effect that people use in interactive news stories:

[image: ESPN Grantland. Note how the line animates as you scroll.]

### [Source: ESPN Grantland](http://www.grantland.com/story/_/id/9175394/out-great-alone) -- Click one of the latter chapters to see the effect in action.

[image: NYT The Russia Left Behind]

### [Source: The New York Times, "The Russia Left Behind"](http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/10/13/russia/)

What are some good ways of doing this? I think both of these examples use [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) for scroll event handling, but any idea how to get the flowing "Indiana Jones"-style line effect? I'm thinking more in terms of using static map images, though I'd also be open to something Google Maps-based.

Many thanks!

Comment: See also http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/

Comment: @JoshLee I hadn't seen that, that's really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: And don't forget about http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/path.html

Comment: @Prinzhorn Oh cool, an example with Skrollr already wired in! **WOOOT WOOOT WOOOT!** ;)